# Too many redirects - GeoIP + htaccess on Wordpress multisite

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, infinite-loop, geoip

I am using Wordpress multisite and trying to set up IP redirects using the Apache GeoIP tool and an `.htaccess` file so that visitors are sent to the correct country site when visiting via my beta.mydomain.com address.

When first tested, I just receive a message saying it’s got stuck in a loop and:

> ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Here is my existing code (Note: GeoIP is enabled elsewhere).

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^GB$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://uk.beta.mydomain.com/$1 [R=302,L]
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^DE$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://de.beta.mydomain.com/$1 [R=302,L]
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^ES$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://es.beta.mydomain.com/$1 [R=302,L]
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^US$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://us.beta.mydomain.com/$1 [R=302,L]

# BEGIN WordPress

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]


# END WordPress
```

Adding this line at the top:

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(uk|us|de|es)\.beta\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
```

improves things a little - the top one will now work, the others only when those above are commented out.

I presume there is something simple I am missing but I have only very limited understanding of this!